# WPF Groupbox header position alignment

Tags: wpf, header, alignment, groupbox

Is it possible to set the position alignment for a `GroupBox` `Header` in WPF?  The default is to place in the top left corner of the `GroupBox` outline but I would like it to be centered at the top. I know that you can set the properties of the text using:

```
<GroupBox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
   <GroupBox.Header> 
      <TextBlock Text="Cash Match" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"/>
   </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

But I'm looking to set the position of it with respect to the `GroupBox` outline.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's simple! Just edit Template of GroupBox:

In Blend, do the following :

- Right click GroupBox > Edit Template > Edit a Copy > OK
- Search for following section:

  ```
  <Border x:Name="Header" Padding="3,1,3,0" 
          Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
      ...
  </Border>
  ```
- Change `Grid.Column` to `2`
- Also set `HorizontalAlignment="Right"`

You have just aligned the header to right!!! But bot the white gap behind it. For that,

- Now search for following section :

  ```
  <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
      <Border.OpacityMask>
          ...
      </Border.OpacityMask>
      ...
  </Border>
  ```
- Add `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"` to the border
- Just above , add following code (this will shift the *"white gap"* behind header to right:

  ```
  <Border.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
  </Border.RenderTransform>
  ```

You are done! You just got a GroupBox with right aligned header!!!

Please tell me if this is what you required.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping it was a property that i overlooked but this approached worked.

Comment: Ok. SO what about center alignment? It's not as trivial as just align to right side.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the group-box-header alinment will result in non-OS-conform controls.

Therefore, I think you won't be able to change this using the default styles. A custom template will solve your problem.