# WPF - Titled Border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there an equivalent in WPF to the Titled Borders that exists in Java's Swing framework?  Below is a link that contains a screenshot of what I am looking for, and some very poor ASCII art.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TitledBorder.htm

```
-------TITLE--------
|                  |
|                  | 
|                  |
|__________________|
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What you're after is called a "GroupBox" in Windows speak.

I've found [this example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Resources/Detail.aspx?ResourceId=672) of how to use it on C# Corner:

```
<Window x:Class="GroupBoxSample.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Margin="10,10,10,10" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"
                  Background="LightGray">
            <GroupBox.Header>               
               Mindcracker Network
            </GroupBox.Header>
           
            <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Regular">
                This is a group box control content.               
            </TextBlock>            
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

A GroupBox can only contain one direct child, so if you want several sub controls you'll have to wrap them in a Grid, a Panel, or a ContentControl.

There's more information on the GroupBox at the MSDN, it's [Class Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupbox.aspx) and [How to Style it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744748.aspx).

If you want the header text to be anything other than left aligned then you'll need to create your own style (as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2111670/59303).

Answer (score 4):

In WPF this would be a GroupBox which in a container control that has a border and a header.

MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupbox.aspx

Here a GroupBox has a header\title of "Employee Data" and contains other controls.

http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC79468.jpg