# WPF looking for way to create border with text labeling the frame

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, xaml

Something like this

[image]

was available in windows forms, but i forget what it was called. But I'm just looking for some good borders to outline regions that allows me to name the region.

Comment: is that a `GroupBox`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF - Titled Border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281568/wpf-titled-border)

Comment: Formerly known as a "Frame" (VB6).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sounds like you need a GroupBox. I wrote an article about these but I won't post a link, as I don't like using StackOverflow for promoting web sites. I will post the opening example XAML though so you can see the effect and check if it's what you want.

```
<Window x:Class="GroupBoxDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="GroupBox Demo"
        Width="250"
        Height="180">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <GroupBox Header="Mouse Handedness">
            <StackPanel>
                <RadioButton Content="Left-Handed" Margin="5"/>
                <RadioButton Content="Right-Handed" Margin="5" IsChecked="True"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Header="Double Click Speed">
            <Slider Margin="5" />
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It looks like:

[image: WPF Groupbox]

Comment: Please, post a link to your article in the comments here. (Or PM me with a link, if you prefer.)

Comment: There is nothing wrong in providing a link to a site of yours for additional information as long as your answer will standby itself if the link rots  away.

Comment: I actually recall the SO founders talking about it being OK to link to external content in an early podcast. I think (as someone else already said) as long as the answer stands on its own doing so is actually a plus.