# WPF GroupBox header Alignment issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, header, groupbox

How can i align the groupBox header to the center rather than the default left positioning.

I read in many post that one can use template but i have no idea about such thing. So please let me know how can i get the header at center.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to modify the Template.

For **Center-Alignment** see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235252/wpf-groupbox-header-customization) by Thomas Levesque
For **Right-Alignment** see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104013/wpf-groupbox-header-postion-alignment) by Mihir Gokani

Uploaded a sample project containing both **Center-Alignment** and **Right-Alignment** here: http://www.mediafire.com/?hd2vbwr97ep7yis

Center-Alignment using the same approach as Thomas

**Usable like this**

```
<GroupBox Header="Centered Header"
          Style="{StaticResource CenteredHeaderGroupBoxStyle}"
          .../>
```

**CenteredHeaderGroupBoxStyle**

```
<local:CenterBorderGapMaskConverter x:Key="CenterBorderGapMaskConverter"/>
<Style x:Key="CenteredHeaderGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#D5DFE5"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                    <Border Grid.ZIndex="2" x:Name="Header" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="3,1,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    <Border RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                        <Border.OpacityMask>
                            <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="7" Converter="{StaticResource CenterBorderGapMaskConverter}">
                                <Binding ElementName="Header" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Border.OpacityMask>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3">
                            <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**CenterBorderGapMaskConverter**

```
class CenterBorderGapMaskConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    // Methods
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Type type = typeof(double);
        if (values == null
            || values.Length != 3
            || values[0] == null
            || values[1] == null
            || values[2] == null
            || !type.IsAssignableFrom(values[0].GetType())
            || !type.IsAssignableFrom(values[1].GetType())
            || !type.IsAssignableFrom(values[2].GetType()))
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        double pixels = (double)values[0];
        double width = (double)values[1];
        double height = (double)values[2];
        if ((width == 0.0) || (height == 0.0))
        {
            return null;
        }
        Grid visual = new Grid();
        visual.Width = width;
        visual.Height = height;
        ColumnDefinition colDefinition1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition colDefinition2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition colDefinition3 = new ColumnDefinition();
        colDefinition1.Width = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
        colDefinition2.Width = new GridLength(pixels);
        colDefinition3.Width = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
        visual.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDefinition1);
        visual.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDefinition2);
        visual.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDefinition3);
        RowDefinition rowDefinition1 = new RowDefinition();
        RowDefinition rowDefinition2 = new RowDefinition();
        rowDefinition1.Height = new GridLength(height / 2.0);
        rowDefinition2.Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);
        visual.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition1);
        visual.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition2);
        Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle rectangle3 = new Rectangle();
        rectangle1.Fill = Brushes.Black;
        rectangle2.Fill = Brushes.Black;
        rectangle3.Fill = Brushes.Black;
        Grid.SetRowSpan(rectangle1, 2);
        Grid.SetRow(rectangle1, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(rectangle1, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(rectangle2, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(rectangle2, 1);
        Grid.SetRowSpan(rectangle3, 2);
        Grid.SetRow(rectangle3, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(rectangle3, 2);
        visual.Children.Add(rectangle1);
        visual.Children.Add(rectangle2);
        visual.Children.Add(rectangle3);
        return new VisualBrush(visual);
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object[] { Binding.DoNothing };
    }
}
```

Comment: You solution worked perfect me for me.....Thanks so so much

But i noticed some difference which doesn't bother me but i thought i should share with you. In normal GropuBox when we insert a Grid, the grid is inside the groupbox with some default margin. Whereas in this case(ur groupBox), the grid starts exactly at the same place as the header. You can try inserting a grid in each groupbox of your sample and you will understand what i am talking about. 

I think it has to do something with the padding or margin. Will check to see in your code....

Thanks a ton once again !!

Comment: @Pankaj Upadhyay: You're right, that's actually really weird. It only happends in **Visual Studio 2010** Designer and not in **Expression Blend 4** and it happends when using the default template created by **Blend**. I'll look into it. Good observation!

Comment: @Pankaj Upadhyay: I don't see anything wrong in the Template so it might be a bug in **VS2010** Designer or maybe I'm missing something

Comment: I dont use Expression blend so can't say much :-P , but thought it is worth disussing ... Just using your solution the way it is.....Thanks

Comment: @Pankaj Upadhyay: Yes, it sure is :) I'll update here if I find out something more on the subject