# WPF - Can't align Groupbox Header to right

Tags: wpf, alignment, dockpanel

I'm new to WPF,

I can't align the groupbox header text "abc" to the right,it's stays on the left, don't know why, can anyone help me please?

```
<Window x:Class="UserInterface.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="625">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>             
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                <GroupBox>
                    <GroupBox.Header>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right">abc</TextBlock>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </GroupBox.Header>
                </GroupBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You'll have to edit the `GroupBox`'s `ControlTemplate` as header is hardcoded to be left aligned in there using `Grid` and column arrangements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104013/wpf-groupbox-header-postion-alignment

Answer (score 1):

You have to **override `Template` of `Groupbox` in case you want to align header to `Right`**. By default it is placed at left in default template.

Key is to

1. Set `Grid.ColumnSpan` to `2` on border hosting Header ContentPresenter.
2. Set `HorizontalAlignment` to `Right` on ContentPresenter.

Here is the XAML which will work:

```
<GroupBox Header="abc">
   <GroupBox.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupBox">
         <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
               <RowDefinition Height="*" />
               <RowDefinition Height="6" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="4,4,4,4"
                    BorderBrush="#00FFFFFF"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                    Grid.RowSpan="3" />
            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="4,4,4,4"
                    BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF"
                    OpacityMask="{x:Null}"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                    Grid.RowSpan="3">
               <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                       CornerRadius="3,3,3,3"
                       BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}">
                 <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                         CornerRadius="2,2,2,2"
                         BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" />
               </Border>
             </Border>
            <Border Padding="3,1,3,0"
                    Name="Header"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" <-- HERE
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2">
               <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Right" <-- And HERE
                                 Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.Header}"
                                 ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}"
                                 ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderStringFormat}"
                                 ContentSource="Header"
                                 SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
             </Border>
             <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
                               ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                               ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"
                               Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                               SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="2"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
          </Grid>
       </ControlTemplate>
   </GroupBox.Template>
</GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to redesign the ContentPresenter inside the template of the Control.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744748%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an example but somehow it also redesigns the GroupBox.

Check this out and see if thats what you are looking for. You are looking for this line

```
<ContentPresenter Margin="4"
                  ContentSource="Header"
                  RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
```

Just add to that:

```
HorizontalAlignment="Right"
```